# regex , select sentence in database exept

Tags: sql, regex

I got part of a sentence in my database like :

```
beautiful house close to the beach
this peaceful touristic area
under a beautiful tree
behind the property
```

I would like to select sentence that does not contain a list of word like 'to','a'

Wanted result:

```
 this peaceful touristic area
 behind the property
```

I figured that I had to use something like

```
SELECT ID_sentence
FROM sentence 
WHERE semi_sentence NOT RLIKE '(.*)[^A-Za-z]to[^A-Za-z](.*)' 
AND semi_sentence NOT RLIKE '(.*)[^A-Za-z]a[^A-Za-z](.*)'
```

but I can't get the regex right and I should probably group the list under one regex

Comment: Try `WHERE semi_sentence NOT RLIKE '[[:<:]](to|a)[[:>:]]'` since I believe this is MySQL.

Comment: What database do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *word boundaries* applied to the *group* of two alternatives listed after `|` operator:

```
WHERE semi_sentence NOT RLIKE '[[:<:]](to|a)[[:>:]]'
```

See [what this regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/vA5dB1/1) (you will get those that do not match since you are using `NOT`, and `\b` is used in PCRE instead of both `[[:<:]]` (leading word boundary) and `[[:>:]]` (trailing word boundary)).

Comment: one last thing, sometime words have special caractere like {, [ , or '. I tried to escape them with `preg_quote` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Then you should not be using word boundaries. Use `(^|[^[:alnum:]])(to|a)($|[^[:alnum:]])`.

Comment: I mean, I got something like `[to]`. I tried `[[:<:]]([to]|a)[[:>:]]`, `[[:<:]](\[to\]|a)[[:>:]]` and `(^|[^[:alnum:]])([to]|a)($|[^[:alnum:]])` but it pull `beautiful house close [to] the beach` if it exist.

Comment: `[` is a special  character, it must be escaped as `\\[`.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can try `'.*?\sto\s.*'` and `'.*?\sa\s.*'`.
2. or add `?` after the first `.*` in you sentence.

thanks.